# library and plugins for jQuery multiple file upload

Tags: jquery, plupload, multiple-file-upload

I'm looking for any jQuery library or plugin for uploading multiple file at a time. I have studied PLupload. But I want to know that which are other library or plugins are available for same functionality. My requirements and priority is listed below

```
1. Multiple file at a time
2. Easy to change CSS as per theme of site
3. Drag and Drop for selecting file
4. Multiple files can be drag and drop at a time
5. Individual file also should be allowed to upload from queue (separate upload button for every file in queue)
```

I know as it is not easy to get all the functionality in single library or plugin. But this list is just my requirements as priority wise. You can also ignore last point too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery file upload.

File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for jQuery.
Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing.
Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/